# How to implement File Upload with AngularJS, Spring-Boot?

Tags: angularjs, spring-boot, file-upload

For uploading the file , 
Angular JS Part:
I am using this in my conroller:

```
var uploader = $scope.uploader = new FileUploader({
  url: '/imageUpload'
```

});

In html:

`<input type="file" nv-file-select="" uploader="uploader" accept="image/png, image/jpeg, image/gif" name="input-file-preview" ng-disabled="em.checked"/>`

Spring-Boot Part(In service method):

```
@RequestMapping(value="/imageUpload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void UploadFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("file uploading ...............");
        /*
        Iterator<String> itr=request.getFileNames();
        MultipartFile file=request.getFile(itr.next());
        String fileName=file.getOriginalFilename();
        File dir = new File("C:\\file");
        if (dir.isDirectory())
        {
            File serverFile = new File(dir,fileName);
            BufferedOutputStream stream = new BufferedOutputStream(
                    new FileOutputStream(serverFile));
            stream.write(file.getBytes());
            stream.close();
        }else {
            System.out.println("not");
        }
        */
    }
```

But I am getting 403 forbidden error , because it is not able to find /imageUpload resource. Anybody can explain me how this fileUploader will work when we will work with spring boot because this code is working fine with upload php file.

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 0):

Server side implementation looks good. From angular service try following using formData with a POST request, it should work.

```
function saveDoc(file) {
                var deferred = $q.defer();
                var formData = new FormData();
                formData.append('file', file);

                $http.post(urls.DOC_URL+'upload', formData,{
                    transformRequest : angular.identity,
                    headers : {
                        'Content-Type' : undefined
                    }})
                    .then(
                        function (response) {
                            deferred.resolve(response.data);
                        },
                        function (errResponse) {
                            alert(errResponse.data.errorMessage);
                            deferred.reject(errResponse);
                        }
                    );
                return deferred.promise;
            };
```

Reference :
[Spring Boot Angular JS file Upload](http://www.devglan.com/spring-boot/file-upload-angularjs-spring-boot-rest)